# issue with cmp in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, cmp

I am using an open source Python code. I think it has been written for Python 2, when I run it in Python3.3 I get this error:

```
TypeError: must use keyword argument for key function
```

pointing to these lines of code:

```
probs = [(word, pool[word]) for word in words if word in pool]
probs.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(y[1],x[1]))
```

Also similar part of the code:

```
       for pname, pprobs in pools.items():
        p = self.getProbs(pprobs, tokens)
        if len(p) != 0:
            res[pname] = self.combiner(p, pname)
    res = res.items()
    res.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(y[1], x[1]))
```

gives the same error.

I am a beginner in Python, so I appreciate if somebody can tell me how should I change the code.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.1.html http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.2.html http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html

Comment: Thanks, that is a great reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmp` has been depracated. Use `key` instead.

```
probs = [(word, pool[word]) for word in words if word in pool]
probs.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Comment: simon: I updated the question, if I change the line `res.sort(lambda x,y: cmp(y[1], x[1]))` to `res.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])`, now I get this new error: `AttributeError: 'dict_items' object has no attribute 'sort'` do you know why? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: items() here does not have a sort method, you might want to use sorted instead: `sorted(res, key=lambda x: x[1])`

Comment: Thanks a lot, so when previously I had this line: `return res`, should I now replace it with `return sorted(res, key=lambda x: x[1])`?

Comment: Yes. And some filler for stackoverflow.